# Get HTTPS images from Instagram api

Tags: jquery, https, instagram

I am making a facebook app, which lets you choose a photo from Instagram. My problem is the app works fine in all browsers except IE, because it is loading insecure content (Instagram images). Anyone know a way around this? My goal is to return https links directly from Instagram in order to skip all later javascript changes.

EDIT: I'm thinking I can change the json object itself before the page loads data. How would I get this working with what I have currently? What am I missing?

```
loadNextPage        : function(data, isInit)
{           
    if (isInit)
    {
        G.moveSelectedAhead();
    }

    // Grab the url for the next page of images
    var url = data.pagination.next_url; 

    // Create new div page
    var $div = $("<div>");
    $.each(data.data, function(key, value){     
        // Create the image element 
        var $img = $('<img>');
            $img.attr('src', value.images.thumbnail.url);
            $img.data('full', value.images.standard_resolution.url);
            $img.data('thumb', value.images.thumbnail.url);
            $("img").each( function() {
                var i = $(this).attr("src");
                var n = i.replace("http://", "https://");
                $(this).attr("src", function() {
                return n;
                });
            });

            // $img.data('full', value.images.standard_resolution.url).replace('http://', 'https://');
            // $img.data('thumb', value.images.thumbnail.url).replace('http://', 'https://');
        $div.append($img);
    });     
    $("img").each( function() {
        var i = $(this).attr("src");
        var n = i.replace("http://", "https://");
        $(this).attr("src", function() {
        return n;
        });
    });
    // Add new page to the slider
    $('.images').append($div);

    // Change the width of the images div since we are 
    // adding another page
    var width = $('.image-content .images').width();
    $('.image-content .images').width(width + G.slideWidth);

    // Check to see if we are on the last page
    if (typeof url === 'undefined')
    {
        $div.addClass('end');   
    }
    else
    {
        $('.next').data('nexturl', url);                    
    }
},
```